# How to prevent/stop valuechanges event while patchValue in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

You can find my problem here with code sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhrppl?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

I want to prevent valuechange subscription while patchValue, because both values are subscribed for valuechange and its overriding the calculation result.

I believe this should be common use case in the application, is there RxJS operator to handle this scenario or any better design?

Answer (score 6):

Angular's reactive forms has an option you can pass to set, patch, etc specifcally for this.

> emitEvent: When true or not supplied (the default), both the statusChanges and valueChanges observables emit events with the latest status and value when the control value is updated. When false, no events are emitted.

Here's an example from your stackblitz, modified:

```js
this.item1.patchValue(result * 0.5, {emitEvent: false})
```

Here's a link to the docs which goes into more detail:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue